# How to remove the attribute value using Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I want to remove an attribute that has already been stored.
For example , as there are users who have a 'surname',

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test01@test.onmicrosoft.com?$select=id,userPrincipalName,surname  

response:
{  
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,userPrincipalName,surname)/$entity",  
    "id": "8e05e09b-c195-4404-87c1-2325767b66cd",  
    "userPrincipalName": "test01@test.onmicrosoft.com",  
    "surname": "ABCDEF"  
}
```

In this case , I want to remove the 'surname'.
Is also not removed when update is null, the value is not changed.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test01@test.onmicrosoft.com
{
    "surname": null
}
```

It is an error to be updated in "".

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test01@test.onmicrosoft.com
{
    "surname": ""
}

response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid value specified for property 'surname' of resource 'User'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "159ef469-f527-4768-b1bd-99ffc3446e5c",
            "date": "2016-06-22T14:35:18"
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to remove.

Answer (score 1):

As of 7/28/2016, the Microsoft Graph now respects removing attribute values by passing 'null', so

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test01@test.onmicrosoft.com
{
    "surname": null
}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Microsoft Graph REST API is not able to remove **Surname** or set this property to **null**.

As a workaround, we can create a new user which not specify this property. Here is the REST for your reference:

```
POST:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
authorization: bearer {token}
{


"accountEnabled": true,

"displayName":"displayName",
"mailNickname":"mailNickname",

"passwordProfile":

{"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn":false,"password":"Password@-1234"},

  "businessPhones": [
    "businessPhones-value"
  ],
"userPrincipalName":"test@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"

}
```

And if you want the Microsoft Graph to support this feature, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I was feedback .